# AES 64 key generation

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I am trying to generate 64 HEX digits to be used as a AES 256 key with no success.
Can somebody point out the mistakes and a better way to generate the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String randomNumber = Convert.ToBase64String (GenerateRandomNumber(32));
            Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);

           string input = randomNumber;
            char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char letter in values)
            {
                // Get the integral value of the character.
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
                // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form.
                string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
                // Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1}", letter, hexOutput);
                builder.Append(hexOutput);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(builder);
        }


        public static byte[] GenerateRandomNumber(int length)
        {
            using (var randomNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var randomNumber = new byte[length];
                randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                return randomNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you need to convert it to a base64 string first. It could be as simple as this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key = GenerateRandomNumber(32);
        var hexEncodedKey = BitConverter.ToString(key).Replace("-", "");
        Console.WriteLine(hexEncodedKey);
    }

    public static byte[] GenerateRandomNumber(int length)
    {
        using (var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[length];
            randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return randomNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. The base 64 is not needed at all. Without base 64, this works with RNGCryptoServiceProvider as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your biggest technical problem is that you used `{0:X}` when you meant `{0:X2}`.  If the value is 10 the former produces "A" and the latter "0A".  Since you've lost where all of the interior zeroes are your number isn't recoverable.

```
internal static string ByteArrayToHex(this byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);

    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        builder.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

(Code copied from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/7cad8486cbabbce0236bdf530e30db7036335524/src/Common/tests/System/Security/Cryptography/ByteUtils.cs#L37-L47)

But it's also pretty unclear why you're rerouting through Base64+ToCharArray+ToInt32.  You're replacing values in the 0-255 range (bytes) with values in the [A-Za-z0-9/=+] rangeset, equivalent to 0-63 (Base64 and all); so you a) wouldn't have a very random key and b) it'll be too long.

Answer (score 2):

.NET framework already has a method Aes.GenerateKey() for generating symmetric keys, please look at this MSDN documentation: [Aes class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx)